# how to convert array of string in json to array of strings in powershell?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have below json

```
{
  "abc": [
    { "def": [ "", "" ] },
    { "ghi": [ "", "" ] },
    { "xyz" : ["\\[dbo\\].\\[abc1\\]", "\\[dbo\\].\\[def1\\]"] }
  ]
}
```

i want to read this json and convert string of xyz element to string array in powershell using below code but its not working.

```
$json = Get-Content "path to json file" | Out-String
$json = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
GetArrayFromJson -json $json
$global:array
Function GetArrayFromJson(){

Param(
    $json       
)

$global:array= ''
     $global:array

    $global:array=  $json.abc.xyz
     $global:array
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "its not working"? You know that you have to create a function **before** you can us it, don't you?

Comment: yes, here i mistakenly wrote it above the function.. but the function is available ..what i mean say from not working that i want the output to be equal to same if i declare the variable as  $global:array = "\\[dbo\\].\\[abc1\\]", "\\[dbo\\].\\[def1\\]". did you get it?

Comment: in simple words, i want to read an element of json which has string array and convert it into string array in powershell

Comment: Hmmm ... but if you use `ConvertFrom-Json`it is already Powershell. You can output it with `$json.abc.xyz`

Comment: right , that is what is done.. please read . the problem is the output of this is not expected  and equal to the situation if i declare the variable to be $global:array = "\[dbo\].\[abc1\]", "\[dbo\].\[def1\]". shouldn't it be ?

Answer (score 2):

That does not fit into a comment ... assumed I have a json string like this:

```
$rawjson = @'
{
  "abc": [
    { "def": [ "", "" ] },
    { "ghi": [ "", "" ] },
    { "xyz" : ["\\[dbo\\].\\[abc1\\]", "\\[dbo\\].\\[def1\\]"] }
  ]
}
'@
```

and I convert it to a Powershell object like this:

```
$json = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $rawjson
```

I can access the "xyz" property like this:

```
$json.abc.xyz
```

When I create a proper function with a single param block! ;-) like this:

```
Function GetArrayFromJson{
    Param(
        $json       
    )
    $json.abc.xyz
}
GetArrayFromJson $json
```

and run it I get both time the same output:

```
\[dbo\].\[abc1\]
\[dbo\].\[def1\]
```